# Serialization issue when using StateServer mode in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, serialization

If my session mode is set to "StateServer", I get a serialization error because I'm storing a list of controls in a session, and adding those into a aspx placeholder control.  Here's the code that I think is problematic:

```
Protected Sub AddCtrl(ByVal ctrl As Control)
   Dim l As List(Of Control)
   If Session("Ctrls") Is Nothing Then
      l = New List(Of Control)
   Else
      l = DirectCast(Session("Ctrls", List(Of Control))
   End If
End Sub
```

Later on in the code, I iterate through the Ctrls session object, and add each control to a placeholder in the HTML.

What can do I to fix this problem?  I tried to create a custom list that inherits from list, and made it serializable and use the custom list instead, but that didn't do it:

```
<Serializable()> _
Public Class MyList 
    Inherits List(Of Control)
```

I tried using ViewState instead and that also didn't do it.  Seeking advice...

Thanks!

Comment: The obvious answer: don't store the controls in the session; only store the *state* of the controls (using straightforward, serializable types) and then recreate the controls from that state data as required.

Comment: I agree, that would be ideal, but will take some redesigning. However, a quick-fix is needed at this point. Any alternatives?

Comment: Is there anything other than session that I could use to persist that will not require serialization?